# How to convert string kind of lat and lang to JSON in ASP.net Core?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

In my action method, I get a string that has lat and lang string value I would convert it to JSON. My string is like this.

```
&quot;[[[{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.71467081484196,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.41189575195313},{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.70254403049943,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.45472526550293},{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.69292492425683,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.402111053466804}]]]&quot;
```

I have used JSON validator, and after that, I understand I must make like this. How to convert the above string JSON format in Asp.net core?

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "lat" : 35.71467081484196,
                "lng" : 51.41189575195313
            },
            {
                "lat" : 35.70254403049943,
                "lng" : 51.45472526550293
            },
            {
                "lat" : 35.69292492425683,
                "lng" : 51.402111053466804
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

---

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Device_Setting(Guid id)
    {
        SetPanelType(PanelTypes.Device);

        var deviceSetting = await dbContext.DeviceSetting.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ds => ds.DeviceSettingId == id);
        var fence = await dbContext.DeviceFence.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.DeviceSettingId == deviceSetting.DeviceSettingId);
        ViewBag.FenceArea = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fence.ShapePath);

        return View(deviceSetting);
    }
```

---

```
function sendFenceData(flag) {
    if (flag) {
        var data = {
            ShapePath: JSON.stringify(ShapePath),
            ShapeType: 'Multiple'
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Panel/Device_Fence',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                alert("اطلاعات با موفقیت ثبت شد.");
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk,I wrote JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fence.ShapePath)

Comment: have you tried just one option? Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty seems to be that your string is both html encoded and escaped JSON. Reversing both of these processes leaves perfectly parsable JSON. Here is an example, reading the values into an array of tuples:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string jsonHtmlEscaped = @"&quot;[[[{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.71467081484196,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.41189575195313},{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.70254403049943,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.45472526550293},{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.69292492425683,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.402111053466804}]]]&quot;";
        Console.WriteLine("Raw string:");
        Console.WriteLine(jsonHtmlEscaped);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var jsonEscaped = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(jsonHtmlEscaped);
        Console.WriteLine("After Html Decode:");
        Console.WriteLine(jsonEscaped);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(jsonEscaped);
        Console.WriteLine("After unescape JSON:");
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var latAndLongRaw = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<System.Text.Json.JsonElement[][][]>(json);
        var latAndLong = latAndLongRaw
            .SelectMany(a => a)
            .SelectMany(a => a)
            .Select(a => (Latitude: a.GetProperty("lat").GetDecimal(), Longitude: a.GetProperty("lng").GetDecimal()))
            .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("After parsing:");
        foreach(var (latitude, longitude) in latAndLong)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Lat: {latitude}, Lon: {longitude}");
        }
    }
}
```

You may play around with this example here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/BkIbGV

Here is the example output:

```
Raw string:
&quot;[[[{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.71467081484196,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.41189575195313},{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.70254403049943,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.45472526550293},{\&quot;lat\&quot;:35.69292492425683,\&quot;lng\&quot;:51.402111053466804}]]]&quot;

After Html Decode:
"[[[{\"lat\":35.71467081484196,\"lng\":51.41189575195313},{\"lat\":35.70254403049943,\"lng\":51.45472526550293},{\"lat\":35.69292492425683,\"lng\":51.402111053466804}]]]"

After unescape JSON:
[[[{"lat":35.71467081484196,"lng":51.41189575195313},{"lat":35.70254403049943,"lng":51.45472526550293},{"lat":35.69292492425683,"lng":51.402111053466804}]]]

After parsing:
Lat: 35.71467081484196, Lon: 51.41189575195313
Lat: 35.70254403049943, Lon: 51.45472526550293
Lat: 35.69292492425683, Lon: 51.402111053466804
```